# DOF not working in Orthogonal view

Tags: camera, depth-of-field, orthographic

I am currently using an orthographic camera in my scene, and I tried to used the camera DOF effect and to my surprise, it didn't work, or perhaps I couldn't make it work. I tried to make the camera perspective again, and it worked. Is there any reason why this is happening or is there a solution to this ? I have seen orthographic artwork rendered with keyshot and software like magicavoxel and they both have DOF in orthographic view. Is blender able to use DOF in orthographic view at all ?

Comment: It works fine here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3P61.png Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.  Add images that illustrate youir issue and that show the settings for the camera.

Comment: What do you mean by 'view'? The 3D View or when rendering? What render engine?